Relation 'Logs' Does note exist (EF Core / PostgreSQL Migration)
Stumped about what's going on here. My LogEntity appears to be implemented no differently than my TenantEntity, and they have the same implementation in my ApplicationDBContext.
I am doing a code-first migration into a locally hosted Postgres server using the following commands:
> dotnet ef migrations add {migrationName}
> dotnet ef database update

which throws this error:

relation "Logs" does not exist

Edit: the migration file does contain the code for creating the Logs table - and the Logs table DOES get created, but the command to run the migration throws this error about 20-30 times before the tables get created.
InitialCreate:
public partial class InitialCreate : Migration
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Logs",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: false),
                Message = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: false),
                Date = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "timestamp without time zone", nullable: false),
                LogLevel = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Logs", x => x.Id);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Tenants",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: false),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Tenants", x => x.Id);
            });
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "Logs");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "Tenants");
    }
}

ApplicationDBContext:
internal class ApplicationDBContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDBContext(DbContextOptions dbContextOptions)
    : base(dbContextOptions)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<LogEntity> Logs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TenantEntity> Tenants { get; set; }
   
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        new LogEntityConfiguration().Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<LogEntity>());
        new TenantEntityConfiguration().Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<TenantEntity>());
    }
}

Entity configurations:
internal class TenantEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TenantEntity>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TenantEntity> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(e => e.Id);
    }
}

internal class LogEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<LogEntity>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<LogEntity> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(e => e.Id);
    }
}

Entity classes:
public class LogEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int LogLevel { get; set; }
}

public class TenantEntity
{
    public string? Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}


Does the table exist? SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'Logs'. Open the Migration file created with dotnet ef migrations add [name]  my guess is that it doesn't have the migrationBuilder.CreateTable( code?

The migration file does contain the CreateTable code for "Logs". Updating my post to reflect this.

Can you try renaming public DbSet<LogEntity> Logs { get; set; } to public DbSet<LogEntity> LogEntries { get; set; } or something else other than Logs?

the Logs table DOES get created, but the command to run the migration throws this error about 20-30 times before the tables get created. indicates something else is trying to access the table before its created. Run the migrate without anything else talking to the dB. If that's not it put Console.WriteLine's in the Migration script and narrow it down that way.

So following up on possible cause that  @Jeremy Thompson had shown me, I performed my typical migration - got my zillion errors - then ran a SELECT * on my Logs table after the migration had completed.
Lo and behold: There are logs from my migration
It appears the problem is that I created a custom logging provider that is dependent on this logs table. When the EF Migration runs, it is pushing logs that are picked up by my logger, which then attempts to save them to my Logs table (which is in the process of being created).
My fix here was to update my appsettings.json, by setting Logging.DBLogger.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore: "Warning"
